# React component in node_modules not transpiled

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

In my Webpack setup, I am currently experiencing something weird I don't understand.

I have created a React component that I loaded via npm into the project, so it's located in `node_modules`. Since I don't want to include all of my dependencies in the created bundle, I have set up `babel-loader` to ignore `node_modules`:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: 'babel-loader',
        },
    ],
},
```

I can use React just fine, but when I want to use my Component, it's not transpiled. Usind third-party packages, everything works.

Does my component loaded via npm need to contain webpack setup so it builds correctly?

Comment: Have you pre-compiled the js files in your module ?. The `main` file pointed in your `package.json` should be in ES5.

Comment: @panther Did not know that! Now it works – but strangely my imports are now undefined. Anything else I need to check?

Comment: @Panther Using library and libraryTarget in webpack conf did the trick. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction – feel free to post this as an answer so I can accept.